# Changing patch colors except one color

Tags: netlogo

I'm creating a program in Netlogo which has shoppers (turtles) moving through a grocery store layout. When they step on a patch it increases in color and when it has no agent on it, it decreases in color, as this will show the paths shoppers take through a store.

My code is:

```
 ask turtles
 [ rt random 360
    fd 1
    set pcolor pcolor + 1 ]

 ask patches with [ (pcolor > 9.9) or (pcolor < 0.1) ]
  [set pcolor 0]

ask patches with [ (count turtles-here = 0) and (pcolor <= 9.9) and (pcolor > 0) ]
  [ set pcolor pcolor - 0.1 ]
```

However, as the aisle patches are blue this is turning them back to black as well. I was wondering what code I could use so patches with `pcolor = 105` will stay blue and not change to black?

Comment: why can't you just add the condition ... `and pcolor != 105` in your final `ask patches`?

Comment: @JenB, Not just only in the last condition, anywhere they change the pcolor. Just a precaution, you say if pcolor > 9.9 or pcolor < .1. This will modify the pcolor if it's 105 since 105 > 9.9. Similarly, the modification of the pcolor in the ask turtles block.

Comment: Note that the turtles could change the color to 105 and be stuck. I don't think this is what you want. Can you be more specific as to what the ask turtles block is suppose to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't change the color of the patches with pcolor = 105. You'll just need to add an additional condition to anywhere you modify the patch color.

```
 ask turtles
     [ rt random 360
        fd 1
        if pcolor != 105[set pcolor pcolor + 1 ]
     ]

 ask patches with [ pcolor != 105 and ((pcolor > 9.9) or (pcolor < 0.1))]
  [set pcolor 0]

ask patches with [pcolor != 105 and (count turtles-here = 0) and (pcolor <= 9.9) and (pcolor > 0) ]
  [ set pcolor pcolor - 0.1 ]
```

Comment: Thank you, I was only adding the condition to one block and that's why it wasn't working.